# What does it mean by extent of uniqueness in the following question?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If we are shown an orthogonal subset of $ℝ^4$ which contains 3 vectors and we found a fourth vector $x_4$ s.t. the 4 vectors form a orthogonal basis for $ℝ^4$. The question asked how do we know that to what extent is $x_4$ unique? I don't quite understand what it's asking?

Comment: Well, $x_4$ is not unique - there's more than one possibility. But it's sort of almost unique - if $x_4$ and $x_4'$ both work then...

Answer (score 1):

Any nonzero multiple of $x_4$ would preserve the mutual orthogonality. On the other hand, those are the only possible variations because the only possible $x_4$ lie in the intersection of the orthogonal complements (hyperplanes) of the 3 given vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask first of all, is $x_4$ unique, meaning there is one and only one possibility? If not, what can you say about the other possibilities? Are they related in a certain way? Certainly you can't choose *any* vector for $x_4$, so try to characterize what the possible choices do have in common.